# conditional cumulative aggregation

Tags: r, aggregate

I've got a data set with cumulative values per year, but not cumulative across years. The value resets to 0 at the start of the year, similar to the set below.

```
   Type Year Month Value
1     A 2013     1    50
2     A 2013     2   100
3     A 2013     3   150
4     A 2013     4   200
5     A 2013     5   250
6     A 2013     6   300
7     A 2013     7   350
8     A 2013     8   400
9     A 2013     9   450
10    A 2013    10   500
11    A 2013    11   550
12    A 2013    12   600
13    A 2014     1    50
14    A 2014     2   100
...  ... ...    ...  ... 
23    A 2014    11   550
24    A 2014    12   600
25    A 2015     1    50
26    A 2015     2   100
27    A 2015     3   150
```

Now I want to add a column Value2, which contains cumulative values for all years, so for Year=2014 the value for Year=2013, Month=12 is added, and for Year=2015 the values for Year=2013&2014, Month=12 are added, similar to the data below:

```
   Type Year Month Value Value2
1     A 2013     1    50     50
2     A 2013     2   100    100
...  ... ...    ...   ...    ...
12    A 2013     12  600    600
13    A 2014     1    50    650
14    A 2014     2   100    700
15    A 2014     3   150    750
...  ... ...    ...   ...    ...    
24    A 2014    12   600   1200
25    A 2015     1    50   1250
26    A 2015     2   100   1300
27    A 2015     3   150   1350
```

I also have a couple of different types, so these need to stay separated. How can this be done?

EDIT2:
I used the following code to generate the data set: `test<-data.frame(Type=rep(c('A','B'),each=36),Year=rep(rep(2013:2015,each=12),2),Month=rep(rep(1:12,3),2),Value=rep(rep(50*(1:12),3),2))`

Comment: In this way you will create a data.frame of all characters. Change to: test<-data.frame(Type=rep('A',36),Year=rep(2013:2015,each=12),Month=rep(1:12,3)‌​,Value=rep(50*(1:12),3))

Comment: Thanks, that solved one problem. I add another Type, your code cumulates across types however. How do I prevent this?
`test<-data.frame(Type=rep(c('A','B'),each=36),Year=rep(rep(2013:2015,each=12),2),Month=rep(rep(1:12,3),2),Value=rep(rep(50*(1:12),3),2))`  
  
I tried  
 `test %>% group_by(Type,Year) %>% mutate(Differences = c(Value[1],diff(Value))) %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(Cumulative = cumsum(Differences))`, but that was not sufficient.

Comment: The edit should do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be to write differences for every year and then sum the differences

```
library(dplyr)
dataframe %>% group_by(Type,Year) %>% mutate(Differences = c(Value[1],diff(Value))) %>% 
group_by(Type) %>% mutate(Cumulative = cumsum(Differences))
```

Comment: I tried it on the my code, see the edit. I would expect the differences to be 50 for every year/month. This is not the case however.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do this in the data.table package

```
# get cumulative sum by ID for each year
test[, "sumMonthYear" := cumsum(Value), by=c("ID", "year")]
# get cumulative sum by ID
test[, "sumYear" := cumsum(Value), by=c("ID")]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. Your way also cumulates the year itself. I only need to add the previous end of year results, see the example.

Comment: @Cuchulainn fixed it to match your example.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you two create an id field in your table so that you know the order of the cumulative sum.

Using the `dplyr` package:

```
dataframe %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(cumulative_year = cumsum(Value2))
```

in your case, instead of using an id we could force the following order:

```
dataframe %>%  group_by_(.dots=list(Year,Month,Value)) %>%    mutate(cumulative_year = cumsum(Value2))
```